# Quotient of Polynomial Ring by this monomial ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

[image]

I am trying to understand this statement regarding Stanley-Reisner rings. Basically my question boils down to how do we see/prove that:

$$k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I_\Delta=k\oplus\bigoplus_{1\leq i\leq n}x_ik[x_i]$$?

Thanks.

Comment: It's because $x_ix_j$ is zero is the S-R ring whenever $i\ne j$.

Comment: I sort of get it now.